# Which is more efficient, order by in the database or sort in Ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have a heavy query that takes a lot of time. It has multiple joins, and I am doing `group by` and `order by` on multiple table's columns. Should I do this `order by` or `group by` at ruby application level, or continue doing it in a MySQL query?

Comment: You have a better chance at Mysql if the data is being indexed, you will get the results faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you should do as much filtering and ordering in the database as possible, and this is especially true when you're only displaying a small subset of all possible records as is the case when paginating.

You'll want to do ordering manually if and only if the logic for ordering is so crazy convoluted it's impractical or impossible to do it in the database itself.

It's worth mentioning that database indexes help considerably when accessing ordered information. Use them whenever you have an `ORDER BY` clause on your query for best results.

Comment: Agreed. DBMs are designed to handle indexes and sorting very efficiently and, as long as the indexes are maintained and the DBM is allowed to run its analysis of the tables regularly, it'll figure out the best ways to handle the sorts, assuming it's a good DBM. Failing to index properly or allow the DBM to analyze the data can degrade performance. Pulling data into the code to sort puts a load on the DB host, the network and the code host and it can be amazing how much work that causes.